# Propositional logic as sets of bit-vectors

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, bit-strings

Consider that formulas in propositional logical can be represented as sets of bit-vectors. For example, a formula $\neg b$ (all bit-vectors of the type $?0?$) with three atomic propositions $a,b$ and $c$ represents the set

$$\{ 000, 101, 001, 100 \}.$$

Now given two sets given by formulas $(a \to b) \lor c$ (lets call this $f$) and $a \lor (\neg c \to b)$ (and this $g$), find a formula that tests whether the sets produced by these formulas are equal, $g$ is a subset of the $f$ and if $g$ is a *proper* subset of $f$.

My idea is that the equality could be tested as follows. If the set produced by the formula

$$\neg (f \Leftrightarrow g)$$

is empty, then the sets are equal. My idea is that for all evaluations of $a,b$ and $c$ the equivalence should produce true value and therefore the negation should produce empty set if $f = g$. For the proper subset test, I think a similar idea could be used:

$$\neg (g \to f).$$

Which should state in my mind that all the elements of $g$ must be in $f$ (for evaluation in which $f$ is true, the implications is also true), but $f$ can have other elements as well. So if it is again a empty set, then $g \subseteq f$. I'm not sure how to device the proper subset thought. Does my tests make sense and is the proper subset a trivial test as well?

Comment: Once you can test for subset, conjoin the test for "not equal" and you are done.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, That is true, but i'm not sure my initial "tests" are correct.

Comment: For the subset test, $g \subseteq f$ you want $g \wedge \neg f$ to be identically false.  Equivalently, $\neg g \vee f$ identically true.  You talk about the *proper* subset test twice; you may want to check that.

Comment: A proposition is true when it's set of "bit vectors" contains all possible bit vectors. I think the question is asking you for a formula that "tests" these conditions in that sense: so you don't want the negations. The formulas should be $f \leftrightarrow g$ (for equals), $g \to f$ (for subset) and $(g \to f) \land \lnot(f \to g)$ (for proper subset). (Aside: your "bit vectors" are called truth assignments or interpretations in most of the literature.)

Comment: @RobArthan, hmmm. I get the equals and the subset, but consider $a \land b$ (the proper subset $\{11\}$) and $a \lor b$ (the superset $\{10, 01, 11\}$). Now the test for proper subset has all possible bit vectors. But for evaluations $a = 0$ and $b = 1$, the test

\begin{align*} &((a \land b) \to (a \lor b)) \land \neg ((a \lor b)
\to (a \land b))\\
&((1 \land 0) \to (1 \lor 0)) \land \neg ((1 \lor 0)
\to (1 \land 0)) \\
&(0 \to 1) \land \neg (1
\to 0) \\
&1 \land 0
\end{align*}
is false. So that would indicate that it is not a proper subset, when it clearly is...?

Comment: I think you have miscalculated in the last step: $1 \to 0$ is $0$, so $\lnot(1 \to 0)$ is $1$.

Comment: @RobArthan, true! My bad.. but then consider $a=1, b=1$.

\begin{align*} &((a \land b) \to (a \lor b)) \land \neg ((a \lor b) \to (a \land b))\\ &((1 \land 1) \to (1 \lor 1)) \land \neg ((1 \lor 1) \to (1 \land 1)) \\
 &(1 \to 1) \land \neg (1 \to 1) \\
 &1 \land 0 \end{align*}